# Making an API call from dockerized web page to back-end server ends up with net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have 2 containers running:

- a front-end nginx-based app/container (web page opened in browser) that tries to make an API call at "/search" endpoint. Webpage is static and is available by copying webpage contents into `/usr/share/nginx/html`.
- a back-end server that is available on port 8080

Why cannot I make a GET request for `/search` so that this request is handled by back-end?

I always get `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` in browser's console even if I have linked them.

Here's my config:

```
services:
   backend:
      image: docker.xxxxx.net/yyyyyy/zzzzzzzz:latest
      expose:
         - "8080"
      ports:
         - "8333:8080"

   frontend:
      build:
         dockerfile: Dockerfile
         context: .
      depends_on:
         - "backend"
      links:
         -  backend
      ports:
         - "80:80"
      volumes:
         - ./build:/usr/share/nginx/html
```

Important note that launching just back-end on another server allows me make API calls (the only problem that arises then is CORS), so the back-end code is ok and the problem must be in wrong docker configuration.

I can clearly open front-end, but I cannot make any API calls: I have tried a lot of things like to make a calls to:

- `http://backend/search?q=test`
- `http://backend:8080/search?q=test`
- `http://backend:8333/search?q=test`
- `http://frontend/search?q=test`
- `http://frontend:8080/search?q=test`
- `http://frontend:8333/search?q=test`

The result is the same. What can be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming GET request is made from your browser, i.e, from the host NOT from the frontend container. As per your config, 8080 is exposed from backend container to the frontend container and port 8333 is exposed to the docker host. Hence `http://backend:8080` is visible only from within frontend container but not from the host machine. So it might have to be `http://<docker_ip>:8333/search?q=test` to get the response from backend container.

Comment: well, if I try to make a call to */search* it will be transformed to `http://<docker_ip>/search` so basically I am calling to <docker_ip>. I even tried to add 8333 port to the call, but then I get `This site can’t be reached`

Comment: I might be wrong, but.... how about http://localhost:8333/search?q=test. What is your environment unix or non-unix? if non-unix, are you using native docker or docker-machine?

Comment: Localhost also gives that `This site can’t be reached`. I am under windows, launching my configs from terminal

Answer (score 0):

Try communicating to source docker via environment variables provided by docker. See [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/#/environment-variables)

Answer (score 0):

handle your CORS error with nginx.

configure in your nginx.conf a reverse proxy.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;

      location /search {
       proxy_pass http://backend:8080;
    }
...
}
```

this (or similar) should solve your net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED permission error

Comment: tried that, not no luck. I even tried to install chrome extension that disables CORS - result is the same.

Comment: @kaytrance did you restart your nginx inside the docker container to get the newest config? try nginx -s reload OR service nginx reload

Comment: yes, of course, I have stopped and relaunched all my docker setup via `docker-compose -f configfile.yml up`. And by the way, when I had CORS-related problems (not related to this setup), the console of the browser had error stating about CORS, but now it's different, so I assume my problem is not CORS related